# setTextAppearance deprecated in API level 23

Tags: android, deprecated

> **public void setTextAppearance (Context context, int resId)
>   Added in API level 1** 
>   
>   This method was deprecated in API level 23.
>   Use setTextAppearance(int) instead.

**My Question**: Why it's been deprecated? Why it doesn't need `Context` anymore? And most importantly, how to use `setTextAppearance(int resId)` for older versions?

Comment: You can do that for older version just check `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` which would be < MarshMallow.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can use `TextViewCompat` from the support/androidX library:

```
    import android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat // for support-library
    import androidx.core.widget.TextViewCompat      // for androidX library

    // ...

    TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(view, resId)
```

Internally it gets the context from the view (`view.getContext()`) on API < 23.

[Source for TextViewCompat](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/TextViewCompat.java)

[Source for TextView (API23)](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-23/blob/master/android/widget/TextView.java)

Comment: I'm creating TextView's using `TextView(context)` and I tried switching to TextViewCompat and it has no public constructor plus I can't cast the newly created TextView and use it that way.  How do you use (androidx) TextViewCompat if you're creating text views programmatically?

Comment: for buttons there is AppCompatButton and setTextAppearance(context, resId)

Answer (score 51):

1. how to use `setTextAppearance(int resId)` for older versions?

   Use it like this:

   ```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
       super.setTextAppearance(context, resId);
   } else {
       super.setTextAppearance(resId);
   }
   ```

   For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33393762/4747587
2. Why it's been deprecated? Why it doesn't need Context anymore?

   The Reason why it is deprecated is there is no need to pass a `context`. It uses the default context provided by the `View`. Look at the source code below. That should explain it.

   ```
   public void setTextAppearance(@StyleRes int resId) {
        setTextAppearance(mContext, resId);
   }
   ```

   The `mContext` here is defined in the `View` class. So you need not pass a `Context` to this method anymore. The `TextView` will use the context provided to it during it's creation. That makes more sense.

**UPDATE**

This functionality is added as part of the Support Library. So instead of `TextView`, use `TextViewCompat` [[documentation]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/TextViewCompat.html). There are also other classes introduced along with this, like `ImageViewCompat`.

Comment: This is awful, why the heck didn't they add setTextAppearance as part of the ContextCompat class? Now we have to wrap all our setTextAppearance methods or run the risk of deprecated code failure in our client code.

Comment: @worked see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37028325/2613692 They did add the method to TextViewCompat class before this question was posted.

Comment: Nice! Thanks @RustamG

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct - here's another way too. In Kotlin I wrote an extension which makes life easier if you do support `SDK 23` and below as well as above.

```
   fun TextView.setAppearance(context: Context, res: Int) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            setTextAppearance(context, res)
        } else {
            setTextAppearance(res)
        }
    }
```