# To change textappearance to medium of dynamically added rows in table layout in min API 17

Tags: android

On click of button btn1 a row is added.I want to change its text appearance to MEDIUM

ERROR-setTextAppearance can not be applied

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {


                                                    TableRow row1 = new TableRow(create_form.this);
                                                    TextView txt1 = new TextView(create_form.this);
                                                    EditText edttxt1 = new EditText(create_form.this);

                                                    txt1.setText("Topic");
                                                    txt1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                                                     txt1.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);**//ERROR ,NOT WORKING**,Call requires API level23(current min is 17)





                                                    row1.addView(txt1);
                                                    row1.addView(edttxt1);

                                                    t1.addView(row1);

                                                }

                                            }


                });
```

Answer (score 2):

Below API level 23 use this:

```
txt1.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
```

Since API 23, you don't need to pass context parameter. Hence, you can simply call:

```
txt1.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
```

Comment: It is saying wrong first argumnet type for txt1.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);

Comment: txt1.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);   On using this app crashes on button click

Comment: What exception are you getting on app crash?

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in Addition to Rohit Sharma's response, you can define custome style for your textViews and set them programmatically, this way `Supposing your style is like this:

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
     <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearanceSmall</item>
     <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    ...
</style>

TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_title); // Your TextView
textViewTitle.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.MyStyle);
```

The benefit is that you can set other important properties like textSize, typeface, textColor, ... with only one call to the .**setTextAppearance** method

Comment: hey one sec.I thought it worked.But it didnt...the method textAppearance is deprecated.

Comment: Glad I could help. please make the answer accepted and upvote, if it helped to solve your problem @SomyaArora

Comment: hey one sec.I thought it worked.But it didnt...the method textAppearance is deprecated.

Comment: Change your compile sdk to  23 and it will be resolved. The deprecated message is because in the Api Level 23, you don't need to pass the context to the setTextAppearance method anymore.

Comment: compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" It is already 23

Comment: minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: You may refer to this question for better understanding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581814/settextappearance-deprecated-in-api-level-23

Answer (score 0):

Found the alternate solution to it-

Instead of changing textappearance change font size as
 txt1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,18);

18sp=Medium text appearance.