# Set a style using java

Tags: java, android

I create a style, added in my textview xml and worked ok, this way:

```
<TextView
                        android:id="@+id/userFeedName"
                        style="@style/feeds_user_connected_style"
                        android:text="@string/user_name"
                        />
```

But I need to create a textview using java and use my style, I tried it:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);

        textView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.feeds_user_connected_style);
        textView.setText(R.string.user_name);
```

But android studio throw the message "setTextAppearance is deprecated". How can I fix it and use my style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your compile sdk version is 23, you can use the setTextAppearance method without a context, using only the id if the R.style file.

Also you may refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581814/settextappearance-deprecated-in-api-level-23)

Answer (score 0):

according to the [TextView docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance%28int%29) you should use `setTextAppearance(int)` without a context from sdk level 23 and up.

Comment: OK i understand. Thanks